# Game development logic (get units in region)

Tags: c++, directx, logic

I am developing a game and I'm having problems. Basically the idea is:

- Player uses a spell at area.
- Engine selects all units in the area and applies an effect on each.

The problem is that the game theoretically possess thousands of units, and run a loop to check if each is within the specified region spend much processing.

Is there any way to index and speed up this process?

Here's an example (its THEORETICAL!!):

```
// Create the unit struct

typedef struct UNIT{

   int ID;
   int x;
   int y;

}unit;

// Initialize the global unit struct

unit* allunits;

// Do some code, expand the array and add more units

void addUnits(){

...

}

// Search for the number of units that are inside a random region using for and the unit array

int unitsInRegion(x1, x2, y1, y2){

  // Spend alot of processing because there is like 10.000 units and we need to look at each X and Y
}
```

I want to mix this kind of task with DirectX as a way to streamline the process of rendering excluding models that are not within sight of view (camera) from the buffers.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Generally you can attach units to a terrain node and then search the nodes for any units.

Comment: You could look into spatial indexing structures like a grid, quadtree or BSP (binary space partitioning) trees (k-d tree etc.)

Comment: You could build some trees, but with only thousands of points and not to many searches per second I don't think it's necessary. First measure, then optimize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to index and speed up this process?

As mentioned in the comments the usual way to do this, are trees like [Quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), [Octrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) or [BSP-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning).

> I want to mix this kind of task with DirectX as a way to streamline the process of rendering excluding models that are not within sight of view (camera) from the buffers.

I think youre looking for View Frustum Culling ([Tutorial](http://zach.in.tu-clausthal.de/teaching/cg_literatur/lighthouse3d_view_frustum_culling/index.html)). You can mix this approach with one of the in the comments mentioned trees to get an efficient culling to all objects in your scene.